# Install VLC on Qubes OS/Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, vlc, dnf, qubes

I recently installed [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) and I would like to install [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) on my *personal* VM which is based on Fedora 23.

To configure RPM-fusion I ran the two following commands (found on the [french fedora documentation](http://doc.fedora-fr.org/wiki/D%C3%A9p%C3%B4t_RPM_Fusion)):

```
$ su -lc 'dnf install --nogpgcheck http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpmfusion/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm'

$ su -lc 'dnf install --nogpgcheck http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpmfusion/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm'
```

First I tried to configure RPM-Fusion using download1.rpmfusion.org server as said [here](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/) but it's not responding.

Then I'm trying to install VLC typing

```
$ sudo dnf -y update
$ sudo dnf install vlc
```

but the VLC package is not found. I've the following error:

```
[user@personal ~]$ sudo dnf install vlc
Last metadata expiration check: 1:23:59 ago on Fri Dec 30 10:18:41 2016.
No package vlc available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Is this an other way to install VLC ? I'm used to use Debian based OS and a simple `sudo apt-get install vlc` is enough.

### Informations

```
[user@personal Downloads]$ dnf repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:33 ago on Fri Dec 30 14:03:49 2016.
repo id                                                                    repo name                                                                                      status
*fedora                                                                    Fedora 23 - x86_64                                                                             46,074
qubes-vm-r3.2-current                                                      Qubes OS Repository for VM (updates)                                                              186
rpmfusion-free-updates                                                     RPM Fusion for Fedora 23 - Free - Updates                                                         380
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                                  RPM Fusion for Fedora 23 - Nonfree - Updates                                                      106
*updates                                                                   Fedora 23 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                   21,532
```

Comment: Tried running `dnf -y update` before attempting to install vlc?

Comment: I tried it, but vlc package is still not found.

Comment: Please add the output of `dnf repolist`

Comment: I typed it, it has loaded something (an update it seems). I added the output into my question.

Comment: As you can see, the rpmfusion repositories weren't added for some reason, and that's why vlc is not found. I suggest you download the two .rpm files and use `dnf localinstall` to install them, then update and `repolist` again to check.

Comment: I did it, and I've edited my question. Now rpmfusion is listed. `dnf update` does nothing everything is up to date, and vlc is still not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50942/discussion-between-schaiba-and-anthonyb).

Comment: AnthonyB, I suggested to visit VLC website and checking which repos can you download VLC?

Comment: For your info: works for FC24 as well.
(I know I shall ad it as a comment and add FC24 tag, but not enough rep, unfortunately)

Comment: @supriady I've already done that, but the problem was rpmfusion was installed but not enabled. I didn't know it was necessary.

Comment: @PawelDebski Thanks for your information :)

Comment: @AnthonyB, You can try to download rpmfusion for Fedora 23 on rpm.pbone.net. I got it there.Hopefully it can help you to install VLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@schaiba found the solution, thanks.

RPM fusion was installed, but not *enabled*. This is the default behaviour. To enable it :

```
$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ sudo vim rpmfusion-free.repo
```

In the first section set `enabled=1` if it's set at 0.

```
$ sudo vim rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
```

Again in the first section set `enabled=1` if it's set at 0

Then, run an update and an install.

```
$ sudo dnf update
$ sudo dnf install vlc
```

Comment: Note that you will also want to enable the "updates" repos: rpmfusion-free-updates.repo and rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo

otherwise you will not receive updates to packages sourced from rpmfusion